# How to arrange the program flow with a login component

Tags: java, loops, authentication

I am (re)writing a java program which involves logging in (and saving/loading passwords). How should I structure the flow of my program? I think it needs to be event based, but I'm not sure how to implement it (threads?). I obviously don't want to use a while loop running forever. The program should be able to sit in the background and do nothing, and only do something when the user logs in.

PS think of spotify, skype, gmail, etc. You log in, and then you have access to the interface and can do what you want to.

Comment: If you are doing any kind of GUI programming you are really going to need to learn about some basic threading concepts. It really isn't that complicated once you get into it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GUI, then you don't need any loop; only `JTextField` for the user, `JPasswordField` for the password and `JButton` for the login and other GUI components compatible with your purpose.

But with command line, you'll have to use loops as command line can't listen to *events*.

Comment: yes i'll be using a GUI. should i have an action listener start a thread?